# How to scroll down the output of coc help without using the mouse?

Tags: neovim, mouse, plugin-coc

When coc prompts with information about what a class / function does there's help to the right, but if I want to scroll down within this help I have to use the mouse. I'm wondering if there's a nicer alternative?

[image: t]

## Edit

I have tried using the following:

```
coc#util#float_scroll({forward})            *coc#util#float_scroll()*

    Return expr for scrolling a floating window forward or backward. ex: >

    nnoremap <expr><C-f> coc#util#has_float() ? coc#util#float_scroll(1) : "\<C-f>"
    nnoremap <expr><C-b> coc#util#has_float() ? coc#util#float_scroll(0) : "\<C-b>"
```

In my `init.vim` as

```
    nnoremap <expr><C-f> coc#util#has_float() ? coc#util#float_scroll(1) : "\<C-f>"
    nnoremap <expr><C-b> coc#util#has_float() ? coc#util#float_scroll(0) : "\<C-b>"
```

I expected to be able to scroll down with `<C-f>` and up with `<C-b>`, neither of these worked though.

Comment: `:help ins-completion` and the sections on the popup menu didn’t give any scrolling keys of this kind. Maybe coc does?

Comment: coc might, I'm not sure, and not sure where to find it.

Comment: Maybe here? https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim/blob/0ff42027ffd0c41aca4bac1b7e9a9c898a14e9ff/doc/coc.txt#L1543

Comment: @D.BenKnoble just tried (edited post) didn't work for me :/

Answer (score 4):

coc#util#float_scroll has been replaced by coc#float#scroll()

The example keymapping has been given in the documentation.

```
if has('nvim-0.4.3') || has('patch-8.2.0750')
          nnoremap <nowait><expr> <C-f> coc#float#has_scroll() ? coc#float#scroll(1) : "\<C-f>"
          nnoremap <nowait><expr> <C-b> coc#float#has_scroll() ? coc#float#scroll(0) : "\<C-b>"
          inoremap <nowait><expr> <C-f> coc#float#has_scroll() ? "\<c-r>=coc#float#scroll(1)\<cr>" : "\<Right>"
          inoremap <nowait><expr> <C-b> coc#float#has_scroll() ? "\<c-r>=coc#float#scroll(0)\<cr>" : "\<Left>"
endif
```

If you want to scroll one line at a time rather than a full page,
then you can specify the number of lines in the second argument as follows.

```
  inoremap <nowait><expr> <C-f> coc#float#has_scroll() ? "\<c-r>=coc#float#scroll(1, 1)\<cr>" : "\<Right>"
  inoremap <nowait><expr> <C-b> coc#float#has_scroll() ? "\<c-r>=coc#float#scroll(0, -1)\<cr>" : "\<Left>"
```

Worked on NVIM v0.4.4 on my macOS.
Coc installed with vim-plug.
Somehow when I installed it by unzipping from the repo it gave an error.

Answer (score 1):

I had to use `scroll(0, 1)` to scroll backwards 1 line (not `scroll(0, -1)`):

```
  inoremap <nowait><expr> <C-f> coc#float#has_scroll() ? "\<c-r>=coc#float#scroll(1, 1)\<cr>" : "\<Right>"
  inoremap <nowait><expr> <C-b> coc#float#has_scroll() ? "\<c-r>=coc#float#scroll(0, 1)\<cr>" : "\<Left>"
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!